# Testing Destroy Action in Rails API Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm building a RESTful JSON API with Rails 4.0 and using mongoid as my database. I'm testing the destroy action for one of my controllers using RSpec. However, when I run my test I receive the  ActionController::UrlGenerationError: as Rails is unable to find a corresponding route. The weird thing is my destroy action is clearly defined in my routes.rb file and my other controller actions within the same resource work fine.

```
        describe "DELETE 'delete credit cards'" do
    before do
        @credit = CreditCard.new(cc_last4: Random.rand(1234) ) 
    end

    it "should return a successful json response" do
        params = {comicbook_uid: @user.comicbook_uid.to_s , 
                  notebook_token: @user.comicbook_token, 
                  cc_id: @credit.id, format: :json } 

        delete :destroy, params

        body_hash = JSON.parse response.body

        expect(body_hash["success"]).to eql true
    end
```

The error that gets generated in my terminal is this:

```
   Failure/Error: delete :destroy, params
   ActionController::UrlGenerationError:

     No route matches {:comicbook_uid=>"52decf924761625bdf000000",  :comicbook_token=>"sfsakjhfk",      
                :cc_id=>BSON::ObjectId('52decf924761625bdf020000'), 
                :format=>:json, :controller=>"credit_cards", 
                :action=>"destroy"}
```

My routes for the credit card resource look like this:

```
 resources :credit_cards, only: [:create, :index, :destroy], 
 :defaults => { :format => 'json'}
```

Thank you in advance and hope can help me out soon!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing an `id` attribute, which is the only param you should actually need.  Moreover, since you are creating your `@credit` object using `CreditCard.new(...)` it won't actually have an id until you persist it to the db.

Replace:

```
it "should return a successful json response" do
    params = {comicbook_uid: @user.comicbook_uid.to_s , 
              notebook_token: @user.comicbook_token, 
              cc_id: @credit.id, format: :json }
```

with:

```
it "should return a successful json response" do
    params = {id: @credit.id, format: :json }
```

and make sure to persist the CreditCard (or set mock expectations for it to be destroyed).

Comment: Where do I need to pass the id attribute? Reviewing my controller spec, I have a before block at the top of file that creates a user. Therefore, the before block here is unwarranted. I understand I need to pass the id attribute but I'm clueless as where to pass it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Are you destroying a user or a credit card?  It would appear that you need to create a creditcard first before you try to destroy it...